# How to join on distinct sub query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have an SQL query that I'm trying to change but I'm afraid my SQL foo is not good enough to figure this one out.

So, I have the following query..

```
DECLARE @OldestSettlementDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @NewestSettlementDate DATETIME;

SET @OldestSettlementDate = '2014-01-05 12:00';
SET @NewestSettlementDate = '2014-01-05 12:00';

SELECT SETTLEMENTDATE, REGIONID, FUEL_TYPE, SUM(SCADAVALUE) AS TOTAL_GENERATION
FROM
    (SELECT SCADA.SETTLEMENTDATE, DETAIL.REGIONID, COALESCE(FUEL.AEMO_FUEL_TYPE, 'Other') AS FUEL_TYPE, SCADA.SCADAVALUE
     FROM DISPATCH_UNIT_SCADA AS SCADA
     LEFT JOIN GR_DUID_TO_FUEL_TYPE AS FUEL ON FUEL.DUID = SCADA.DUID
     LEFT JOIN DUDETAILSUMMARY AS DETAIL ON DETAIL.DUID = SCADA.DUID
     AND SCADA.SETTLEMENTDATE BETWEEN DETAIL.START_DATE AND DETAIL.END_DATE
WHERE SCADA.SETTLEMENTDATE BETWEEN @OldestSettlementDate AND @NewestSettlementDate)
AS X
GROUP BY SETTLEMENTDATE, REGIONID, FUEL_TYPE
ORDER BY SETTLEMENTDATE DESC, REGIONID, FUEL_TYPE
```

And currently it is returning results like this..

```
SETTLEMENTDATE  REGIONID    FUEL_TYPE       TOTAL_GENERATION
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Black Coal  5593.876490
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Hydro       115.674860
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Liquid Fuel 0.000000
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Natural Gas 475.541690
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Other       152.471500
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Wind        153.175650
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 QLD1    Black Coal  5176.610039
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 QLD1    Hydro       40.795000
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 QLD1    Liquid Fuel 0.000000
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 QLD1    Natural Gas 1402.728840
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 QLD1    Other   51.254405
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 SA1 Brown Coal  274.644050
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 SA1 Liquid Fuel 0.000000
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 SA1 Natural Gas 365.815960
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 SA1 Other       82.600000
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 SA1 Wind        968.568336
```

The problem is, I want all fuel types to appear for every settlement date and region. For example, Brown Coal should show up for NSW1 with a total generation of 0.

```
2014-01-05 12:00:00.000 NSW1    Brown Coal       0.000000
```

I know I'm probably going to have to join on the following sub-query but I'm not sure how it fits into the above query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AEMO_FUEL_TYPE AS FUEL_TYPE
FROM GR_DUID_TO_FUEL_TYPE
```

Thanks.

Comment: rather unfortunate concatentation: "DUDETAILSUMMARY "

Comment: lol. yeah, it's not our database schema. We just have to use it in our software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with your list of fuel types:

```
WITH FUEL_TYPES AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT AEMO_FUEL_TYPE AS FUEL_TYPE
   FROM GR_DUID_TO_FUEL_TYPE
)
```

and your list of dates, and regions:

```
, REGIONS AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT REGION
   FROM DUDETAILSUMMARY
)
, DATES AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT SETTLEMENT_DATE
   FROM DISPATCH_UNIT_SCADA
   WHERE SCADA.SETTLEMENTDATE BETWEEN @OldestSettlementDate AND @NewestSettlementDate
)
```

Now do a cross join between them

```
, ALL_COMBOS AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM DATES, REGIONS, FUEL_TYPES
)
```

This gives your rows. Now you could join this to your current set of results to make sure you're not losing any, or you could use it to join to the underlying tables and pull the data out. Plenty of space for optimising, of course, but this should be a useful start.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it looks correct. Thanks. I didn't test it though. I ended up going with a very similar solution using C# LINQ.